# How to calculate CVaR in SAS?

Tags: sas

Has anyone already done the calculation for CVaR (Conditional Value at Risk) in SAS? Can I have an example or reference material please?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of model are you using?  @Joe is correct that out of the box SAS you need PROC RISK.  You can do the math yourself with IML, the complexity of that will depend on your risk model.

Comment: I'm sort of iffy on whether this is on-topic or not, but if it's asking for how to do it _not_ in PROC RISK, I think this is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Value at Risk is a value provided by the [SAS Risk Dimensions](https://support.sas.com/software/products/riskdimen/examples/distortionmeasures.html) product, available through `PROC RISK`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Joe!